# Open a bootstrap modal by pressing a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I search to open the modal `#LoginModalStart`, with a checkbox, but the page open this modal with every checkbox.

Can you help me ?

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e) {
            if (e.target.checked) {
                $("#LoginModalScreenplay").modal();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please put the HTML/CSS/JS in a snippet for us to troubleshoot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('input[type="checkbox"]')` targets *every* checkbox on your page. You probably want to target the specific checkbox. Something like this

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my-special-checkbox">
```

```js
$('#my-special-checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
            if (e.target.checked) {
                $("#LoginModalScreenplay").modal();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `show` to `modal` method:

```
$('#LoginModalScreenplay').modal('show')
```

Answer (score 1):

You use this,

```
<input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="my-special-checkbox" value=1>
<input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="my-special-checkbox" value=2>
<input  name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="my-special-checkbox" value=3>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e) {
        var x = $(this).val();
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);

        if(x==1){
            $("input[value="+x+"]").prop('checked', true);
            $("#LoginModalScreenplay").modal(); //or $("#LoginModalScreenplay").show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```